# Calcular la media anual a partir de datos trimestrales

Tags: r, rstudio

Necesito calcular la media anual del PIB a partir de datos trimestrales. Por ejemplo, como se muestra en la imagen que adjunto, tengo datos del PIB nominal para cada trimestre desde 1995 hasta 2021, y necesito calcular la media para 1995, 1996...2021. He intentado meanEveryN pero no me sale... Os agradecería si alguien me pudiera dar alguna indicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

---

He seguido provando, i con el código meanEveryN me ha salido:

`library(Thermimage)`

`mitjana_T <- meanEveryN(PIB$PIB_nominal,n=4,lag=round(0),showsamples = TRUE)`

`mitjana_T <- as.tibble(mitjana_T)`

`Anys <- c(1995:2021)`

Output:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque necesito asignar los valores de los años... De momento he creado un vector con datos desde 1995 hasta 2021, y necesitaría sustituir los valores de la columna "Sample" por este nuevo vector de los años. Si alguien me puede dar indicaciones estaré muy agradecida.

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida Maria a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola María, por favor, no pegues una pantalla que no ayuda, es mejor que copies una muestra de tus datos, usa el comando `dput(head(tu_df, 20))` , la salida la copias editando tu pregunta, sino tenemos que tomarnos el trabajo antes de responder de copiar a mano el ejemplo de la imagen, hay un muletilla en el sitio "ayudanos a ayudarte".  Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien quieres sacar la media de los cuatro trimestres de cada año. Para eso necesitamos primero tener una variable para el año y otra para el trimestre (en realidad solo necesitamos `ayo` pero agregue trimestre por cualquier cosa). Luego agrupar por la variable de año y sacamos la media. Todo lo anterior lo hacemos usando `dplyr`. Usamos la función `gsub` para extraer el año y el trimestre.

```
df<-read.table(text="
    Any Pip_nominal
    1995T1 1
    1995T2 2
    1995T3 3
    1995T4 4
    1996T1 5
    1996T2 6
    1996T3 7
    1996T4 8", header =T)

library(dplyr)

df%>%
    rowwise()%>%
    #Creams una columna para el año y otra para el trimestre
    mutate(ayo = gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", Any),
        trimestre =gsub(ayo,"",Any))%>%
    group_by(ayo)%>%
    summarise(mean(Pip_nominal))
```

He creado un ejemplo sencillo de la data pero en tu caso tenderas que cambiar `df` por el nombre de tus datos y verificar que la variable `Any` sea de tipo character y `Pip_nominal` de tipo numérico.

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas sumarizar por año vas a tener que "separar" el año y el trimestre de la variable `Any`. Si, usas `tidyverse`, podrías usar `separate()` para dividir `Any` en dos columnas, a partir de una posición, luego, simplemente se agrupa por trimestre y se sumariza la media.:

```
df %>% 
  separate(Any,  
           into = c("Año", "Trimestre"),
           sep = 4) %>% 
  group_by(Año) %>% 
  summarise(mean(Pip_nominal))
```

Con R estándar podrías hacer algo muy parecido: creamos la columna solo con el Año y luego agrupamos por esta columna y calculamos la media de `Pip_nominal` de cada grupo/año:

```
df$Año <- substr(df$Any, 1, 4)
aggregate(Pip_nominal ~ Año, df, mean)
```